# Play framework running inside docker not accessible from localhost

Tags: java, playframework, docker

I am on `Ubuntu 14.04` and using docker to run Play Framework application in Java. The tool used to automate the build is [ingensi-play-framework](https://hub.docker.com/r/ingensi/play-framework/).

The command to start the application within docker is

```
docker run -d -v /path/to/play/project:/app:rw -P ingensi/play-framework
```

taken from the above link. After this, when I run `docker ps`, I get this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
3eb2285118dc        ingensi/play-framework   "activator run"          14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:32785->8888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32784->9000/tcp   hungry_hopper
```

and I hit `localhost:32784`, I get the message

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

on Google Chrome. I searched on the Internet but to no avail. Please help.

Comment: Check your server log via `docker logs hungry_hopper` ("hungry_hopper" is from your ps command, if you start again you might get a different name) to say where goes wrong. It seems your service is not started correctly within docker.

Answer (score 1):

Try to publish the specific port of your application, from the container, to the host. See the -p option of the [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command.

For example, if you want to expose on the same port on localhost (considering this port is not already used), your command becomes:

```
docker run -d -v /path/to/play/project:/app:rw -p 9000:9000 ingensi/play-framework
```

Comment: Your application is not started inside the container or not listening on that port. You should check the container logs.

Comment: You can run a bash inside the container (run docker exec -i -t  container_id bash) and inside, check if your application is listening by running telnet localhost 9000

Answer (score 0):

try to type http://0.0.0.0:9000 on your web browser, it works for me.